# Как передавать в переменной CSS значение свойства inherit?

Tags: html, css

На примере ниже:

1. `.pl_inherit: var(--inherit)` = `inherit` = **не работает**...
2. `.pr_inherit: inherit` = **работает**.

Как пофиксить?

```css
:root {
  --inherit: inherit;
}

.pl_inherit {
  padding-left: var(--inherit);
}

.pr_inherit {
  padding-right: inherit;
}

.parent {
  background-color:red;
}

.parent__child {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent" style="padding-left:30px; padding-right: 30px">
  <div class="parent__child pl_inherit pr_inherit">123</div>
</div>
```

Comment: А вы уверены, что `var(--inherit)` хоть для каких-то свойств работает? Есть подозрение, что inherit в этом случае будет относиться к `:root`, а не к элементу, в который вы назначаете переменную.

Comment: *Есть подозрение, что inherit в этом случае будет относиться к :root, а не к элементу, в который вы назначаете переменную* - вероятно, так и есть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Провел несколько тестов, возможно, окажется полезным.
Сразу скажу, что `var(--inherit)` даёт такой же результат, как и применение любой несуществующей переменной, тесты внизу, кроме этого, в sass передача `inherit` через переменную нормально работает, [пример](https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-pine-pkdtjp?file=/src/styles.scss).

CSS свойства можно поделить на наследуемые (color, font-family, font-size и т.п.) и ненаследуемые (height, width, padding, margin, и т.п.). См. [таблицу свойств](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/propidx.html) (колонка Inherited), .

Важно! Ненаследуемые свойства **могут** быть переданы потомкам через `inherit`, но автоматически **не** наследуются потомками.

Как известно, обработка модификаторов происходит следующим образом.

- Родительский наследуемый модификатор. (меньший по весу)
- Класс-модификатор 1.
- Класс-модификатор 2.

Модификатор 1 и модификатор 2 равны по весу, но тяжелей чем наследуемое св-во.
Из двух модификаторов применится тот, который указан последним.(через атрибут `style` или с `!important` не рассматриваем, т.к. у них максимальный вес)

**Что происходит, когда применяем `var(--inherit)` или несуществующая переменная**

Происходит сброс применения **одноуровневых** модификаторов. Класс-модификатор 1 и 2 игнорируются и не применяются/ломаются, и используется значение модификатора при инициализации (колонка [initial value](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/propidx.html)).

Далее происходит стандартное поведение CSS.

- на наследуемые модификаторы начинают действовать модификатор родителя
- ненаследуемые просто сбрасываются на значение при инициализации.

Ниже 2 примера - для наследуемого свойства `color` и для ненаследуемого `height`.

У свойств margin, padding, font-size, font-family поведение аналогично их типу наследуемости.

[Список всех свойств.](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/propidx.html)

**`color``**

Срабатывает стандартное наследование от родителя, `color` от класса `.child` игнорируется.

```css
:root {
  --inherit: inherit;
}

.parrent {
  color: black;
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  color: blue; /*Цвет родителя*/
}

.child {
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightgreen;
  color: yellow; /*цвет потомков*/
}

.modifier {
  color: red; /*цвет модификатора*/
}

.var-inherit {
  color: var(--inherit);
}

.var-undefined {
  color: var(--empty);
}
```

```html
<div class="parrent">
  <div class="child">Обычный потомок</div>
  <div class="child modifier">Потомок с модификатором</div>
  <div class="child modifier var-inherit">var-inherit цвет родителя</div>
  <div class="child modifier var-undefined">var-undefined цвет родителя</div>
</div>
```

**`height`**

`height` сбрасывается в auto, класс `.child` игнорируется.

```css
:root {
  --inherit: inherit;
}


html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parrent {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: 800px;
}

.child {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.modifier {
  height: 200px;
}

.var-inherit {
  height: var(--inherit);
}

.var-undefined {
  height: var(--empty);
}
```

```html
<div class="parrent">
  <div class="child">Обычный child высота 100px</div>
  <div class="child modifier">child с модификатором высоты 200px</div>
  <div class="child modifier var-inherit">var-inherit</div>
  <div class="child modifier var-undefined">var-undefined</div>
</div>
```